# DNSMasq forwarding doesn't work!

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq

I want only one DNS for all my local network, when this DNS doesn't know a domain name I want that it ask to router DNS(192.168.1.1) or Google(8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).

I installed and configured DNSMASQ, it works well with local domain names but the forwarding doesn't work.

These are my actual configurations:

DNS: dnsmasq
Firewall open for DNS requests:

```
$ ufw allow 53
```

To solve the error with port 53 in use I disable systemd-resolved:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
$ sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
```

Even though systemd-resolved is disabled, NetworkManager also dynamically modifies the symbolic link resolv.conf, I fixed that with:
    $ sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf

```
$ sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver ::1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

And I put the overwrite protection flag:

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

I found trust anchors in internet and I downloaded in /usr/share/dnsmasq/trust-anchors.conf :

```
# The root DNSSEC trust anchor, valid as at 10/02/2017

# Note that this is a DS record (ie a hash of the root Zone Signing Key) 
# If was downloaded from https://data.iana.org/root-anchors/root-anchors.xml

trust-anchor=.,19036,8,2,49AAC11D7B6F6446702E54A1607371607A1A41855200FD2CE1CDDE32F24E8FB5
trust-anchor=.,20326,8,2,E06D44B80B8F1D39A95C0B0D7C65D08458E880409BBC683457104237C7F8EC8D
```

This is a summary of /etc/dnsmasq.conf configurations that I made:

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
conf-file=/usr/share/dnsmasq/trust-anchors.conf
dnssec
dnssec-check-unsigned   
strict-order
no-resolv
no-poll
server=192.168.1.1
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
local=/jorgecode/
listen-address=::1,127.0.0.1,192.168.1.50
no-dhcp-interface=wlp1s0,lo,enp2s1
expand-hosts
domain=jorgecode
log-queries
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq.log
```

Checking the syntax:

```
$ dnsmasq --test
dnsmasq: syntex check OK.
```

The hosts table is:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost compaq
192.168.1.1     router
192.168.1.50    compaq
192.168.1.46    rpi

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Reseting the services:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager dnsmasq
```

My clients was configured by gnome gui:

```
Settings > WIFI > IPV4 > DNS > Automatic: OFF
DNS: 192.168.1.50
$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

And I don't make any other changes over network configurations.

Testing done on DNS server and clients:

/var/log/dnsmasq.log:

```
Jul 18 14:04:07 dnsmasq[12031]: query[A] router.jorgecode from 192.168.1.45
Jul 18 14:04:07 dnsmasq[12031]: /etc/hosts router.jorgecode is 192.168.1.1

Jul 18 14:05:38 dnsmasq[12031]: query[A] google.com from 192.168.1.45
Jul 18 14:05:38 dnsmasq[12031]: forwarded google.com to 8.8.4.4
Jul 18 14:05:38 dnsmasq[12031]: dnssec-query[DS] com to 8.8.4.4
Jul 18 14:05:38 dnsmasq[12031]: reply com is BOGUS DS
Jul 18 14:05:38 dnsmasq[12031]: validation google.com is BOGUS
Jul 18 14:05:38 dnsmasq[12031]: reply google.com is 172.217.16.238
```

Digging a local address:
    $ dig router.jorgecode

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.8-Ubuntu <<>> router.jorgecode
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 37043
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;router.jorgecode.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
router.jorgecode.   0   IN  A   192.168.1.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: ::1#53(::1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 18 13:34:23 CEST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 61
```

Lookup a local address:

```
$ nslookup router.jorgecode
Server:     ::1
Address:    ::1#53

Name:   router.jorgecode
Address: 192.168.1.1
```

Digging an external address:

```
$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.8-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 27637
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; Query time: 14 msec
;; SERVER: ::1#53(::1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 18 13:34:52 CEST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 39
```

Lookup an external address:

```
$ nslookup google.com
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from ::1, trying next server
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find google.com: SERVFAIL
```

ERRORS:

Digging: **;google.com.         IN  A**

Lookup: **server can't find google.com: SERVFAIL**

Comment: If I understand this correctly You would have to configure all the clients the same way i.e. with the same dnsmasq config...

Comment: Yes, I would like all clients to use the dnsmasq server exclusively as a name server.
If the dnsmasq does not know the address sends the query to google or the router (It has a DNS) and respond to clients as it knew the address.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I meant that You would have to add the same dnsmasq config for each client separately. Then they will work in exactly the same manner.

Comment: I followed this guide and got it working https://linuxhint.com/dnsmasq_ubuntu_server/
I think you need to add your new nameserver to resol.conf with something like ``echo "nameserver 192.168.1.1" >> sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf``